# Oracle Bucket seems to corrupt tar.gz files

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

when pushing a tar.gz file in an Oracle Cloud Bucket. It seems to get corrupted.

```
#before push
[user]$ file fichier.tar.gz gzip compressed data, from Unix, max compression
#after download from bucket 
[user]$ file fichier.tar.gz : data
```

Comment: How did you upload the file?

Comment: I used a pre-authenticated url:
```
curl -X PUT https://objectstorage.eu-frankfurt-1.oraclecloud.com/p/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/n/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/b/xxxx/o/myfile.tar.gz
```

Comment: Finally used rclone to upload the file. It works like a charm.